# JAXB How to add namespace URL as an attribute of the element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I am new to JAXB library and not able to get the solution for adding **xmlns** to the elements in XML and get rid of default namespaces (like ns2, ns3). I have generated the POJOs using wsimport command.

**My XML**

```
<ns3:CheckDocumentValid xmlns="https://wwww.e-gov.az" xmlns:ns2="http://voen9900037691.az.x-rd.net/producer" xmlns:ns3="https://www.e-gov.az">
            <ns3:CheckDocumentValidRequest>
                <ns2:Authentication>
                    <RequestName>requestname</RequestName>
                    <RequestKey>requestkey</RequestKey>
                </ns2:Authentication>
                <ns2:DocumentInformation>
                    <DocumentType>string</DocumentType>
                    <DocumentNumber>string</DocumentNumber>
                    <DocumentPin>string</DocumentPin>
                </ns2:DocumentInformation>
                <ns2:SellerInformation/>
            </ns3:CheckDocumentValidRequest>
        </ns3:CheckDocumentValid>
```

**Desired XML:**

```
<CheckDocumentValid xmlns="https://www.e-gov.az">
      <CheckDocumentValidRequest>
        <Authentication xmlns="http://voen9900037691.az.x-rd.net/producer">
          <RequestName xmlns="https://wwww.e-gov.az">string</RequestName>
          <RequestKey xmlns="https://wwww.e-gov.az">string</RequestKey>
        </Authentication>
        <DocumentInformation xmlns="http://voen9900037691.az.x-rd.net/producer">
          <DocumentType xmlns="https://wwww.e-gov.az">1</DocumentType>
          <DocumentNumber xmlns="https://wwww.e-gov.az">P224526</DocumentNumber>
          <DocumentPin xmlns="https://wwww.e-gov.az">ASDFGHJ</DocumentPin>
        </DocumentInformation>
        <SellerInformation xmlns="http://voen9900037691.az.x-rd.net/producer"/>
      </CheckDocumentValidRequest>
    </CheckDocumentValid>
```

Please refer below code for marshalling object to XML

```
String value;
JAXBContext jaxbContext = getJaxbContext(obj);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
    
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
jaxbMarshaller.marshal(obj, sw);
value = sw.toString();
```